# Linear Programming constraints for biggest sphere inside region

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Let $v_0, ..., v_n \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be vectors and let $k_0, ...,k_n$ be positive numbers.

There is a region $\Pi$ defined as $\Pi = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3\;|\;v_i^tx \le k_i \}$

The problem is to find the center and radius of the biggest sphere inside this region.

How can I write this problem as a LP problem? How to identify the *decision variables*, the *objective function* to be optimized and the *constraints*?

---

The decision variables should be the center and the radius of the sphere.

The objective function should be to maximize $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$.

I'm not being able to visualize $\Pi$, so I'm stuck at defining the contraints for the center and the radius.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2459626

Comment: not as LP and not a sphere, but https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456854/finding-the-maximum-volume-inscribed-ellipsoid-using-cvx/2457011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each point in a circle with center $c$ and radius $r$ to satisfy $v_i^T x \leq k_i$, you need (1) that $c$ satisfies $v_i^T c \leq k_i$, and (2) the distance between the circle and the line $v_i^Tx = k_i$ to be at least $r$. The first condition is obviously linear. The second condition we can express using [a well known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line):
$$\frac{|v_i^Tc-k_i|}{||v_i||} \geq r,$$
from which we can remove the absolute values due to the first condition:
$$\frac{k_i-v_i^Tc}{||v_i||} \geq r.$$
This is also a linear constraint.

The objective you can replace with $\max r$, since a monotone transformation of the objective function does not change the location of the optimum (merely its value).